# WordPress installation on localhost

Tags: wordpress, authentication, localhost

I am getting this error when I try to install WordPress on my localhost. I have already tried changing the table prefix but it still doesn't fix it. Also if I try to login it give me invalid username and password error.

[image]

Comment: You could try to delete the installation folder once you've installed it?

Comment: Is there any valuable data in that database? If not you could `DROP` it and recreate an empty one.

Comment: I have reinstalled WordPress again.

Comment: Still not fixing it, also I have dropped that database and made a new one still can't fix it. :/